# ZFS datasets attribute inheritance

Tags: filesystems, solaris, zfs

I have a ZFS filesystem on a Solaris system. In one pool I have an ISCSI share and an NFS share.

```
zfs list
tank                       1,01G  2,88G  24,0K  /tank
tank/nfs                   24,0K  2,88G  24,0K  /tank/nfs
tank/vdisk                 1,01G  3,89G  10,7K  -

root@storage:~# zfs get sync tank
NAME  PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
tank  sync      standard  default
root@storage:~# zfs get sync tank/nfs
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
tank/nfs  sync      standard  default
root@storage:~# zfs get sync tank/vdisk
NAME        PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
tank/vdisk  sync      standard  default
```

If I set the `sync` attribute on `tank` to `disabled`, it is also set on the child datasets:

```
root@storage:~# zfs set sync=disabled tank
root@storage:~# zfs get sync tank/nfs
NAME      PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
tank/nfs  sync      disabled  inherited from tank
```

Is this normal? I thought that this should not be the case. Is there another attribute that controls this behavior?

Comment: This is normal. Read : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gazup/index.html

Comment: Ye, true, I already know that. But I did the sync=disabled after the creation of datasets, and I have changed the atribute to the parent. I did not make explicitly to tank/nfs to inherit. It seems like if I change an atribute, all the children will inherit it automatically and live. Thought this was not the case.